# 2001 pontiac montana sw- what is the wheelbase length?

Tags: pontiac, montana

I have a 2001 Pontiac Montana SW. I assume the SW means short wheelbase. Is the wheelbase 112 or 120 inches in length?

Answer (score 4):

Wheelbase is the distance from center of front wheel to center of rear wheel.[image: Tape measure]

Comment: Make sure the front wheels are straight when measuring.

Comment: That's a nice measuring tape.  Good resolution.  Nice contrast between the faux chrome and the yellow.  All in all, very nice balance.  +1

Answer (score 1):

The SWB wheelbase is 112", the LWB is 120". The total vehicle length for the SW is 187.3"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontiac_Montana